# Can a website have multiple CNAMEs like WWW?

Tags: web, dns, cname

Basicaly it's the same www.domain.com and domain.com, because it's an alias. But, can i create other CNAME like home.domain.com?
And if i put www.domain.com, domain.com and home.domain.com those will show me the same: the main page of the website.

I tried to do that, but when i enter to home, it shows me an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzvO3.jpg

1. Can a website have multiple CNAMEs?
2. In case of yes, how many CNAMEs like that can a website have?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. Update your different subdomains in your dns configuration pointing to your server's IP address.
2. Create [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) in your webserver if it's apache or search for the equivalent if you use another one.

To emulate the first one you can edit your hosts file adding the different subdomains pointing at your ip and this way check that your Virtual Hosts are working.